# How to Upload txt file with Cypress for API Testing - XMLHTTPRequest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, file-upload, blob, cypress

I'm trying to test an endpoint which will upload a file and give 200 response status code in cypress. As per some research cy.request cannot be used to upload a file for multipart/form-data so we need to use XMLHttp to upload such files. I have created below file to test the api but it doesn't work. Can someone please help what's wrong with my code ? Thank you.

Added below code under support/commands.ts(I will require a header to pass token from auth endpoint)

```
// Performs an XMLHttpRequest instead of a cy.request (able to send data as FormData - multipart/form-data)
Cypress.Commands.add('multipartFormRequest', (method,URL, formData,headers, done) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, URL);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    if (headers) {
        headers.forEach(function(header) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
        });
    }
        xhr.onload = function (){
            done(xhr);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (){
            done(xhr);
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
})
```

Test file to call multipartFormRequest:

```
const fileName = 'test_file.txt';
                    const method = 'POST';
                    const URL = "https://fakeurl.com/upload-file";
                    const headers = api.headersWithAuth(`${authToken}`);
                    const fileType = "application/text";

                    cy.fixture(fileName, 'binary').then((res) => {
                        const blob = Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(res, fileType);
                            const formData = new FormData();
                            formData.append('file', blob, fileName);

                            cy.multipartFormRequest(method, URL, headers, formData, function (response) {
                                expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
                            })
                        })
```

I'm getting this error message:-
Now, I'm getting status code as 0.

Comment: Try `fetch` instead. Also check for cors, check the console log, check network tab in dev tools.

Comment: @John, I'm running with cypress so I don't see any error in log from dev tools.  Is there any example with fetch that i can refer to ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/justsml/529d0b1ddc5249095ff4b890aad5e801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
const blob = Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(res, fileType);
```

and remove the `.then()`.

See [Cypress.Blob](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/blob#History)

> **History**
>
> Version 5.0.0
> Changes:
> Return type of arrayBufferToBlob, base64StringToBlob, binaryStringToBlob, and dataURLToBlob **methods changed from `Promise<Blob>` to `Blob`**

Comment: This will atleast remove the blob function error. However, now I'm getting response with different event status. any idea what's wrong here @hiram

Answer (score 1):

```
describe("Upload image", () => {
it("upload first image", () => {

    const fileName = "image.jpeg";
    const method = "POST";
    const url = "https://api-demo.com/1";
    const fileType = "image/jpeg";
    cy.fixture(fileName, "binary")
        .then((txtBin) => Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(txtBin))
        .then((blob) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image_data", blob, fileName);
            formData.append("image_format", "jpeg");
            cy.form_request(method, url, formData, function (response) {
                expect(response.status).to.eq(200)

            }
            );

        })

});
```

});

```
Cypress.Commands.add('form_request', (method, url, formData, done) => {
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("device", "331231");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("city", "bangalore");
xhr.onload = function () {
    done(xhr);
};
xhr.onerror = function () {
    done(xhr);
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).