# Uploading multipart/form-data from text file using Cypress

Tags: typescript, xmlhttprequest, cypress

I've been at this all day and I really need a nudge in the right direction.

My dependencies are -

```
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "cypress": "^8.1.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8"
  }
```

I have a fixture called `uploadBlob.txt`

This is what it looks like -

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7BhOPSS0NpEAppSA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadedFileName"

Prod_CA.ACI
------WebKitFormBoundary7BhOPSS0NpEAppSA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="OrderId"

7815968_13735
------WebKitFormBoundary7BhOPSS0NpEAppSA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Options[orderid]"

7815968_13735
------WebKitFormBoundary7BhOPSS0NpEAppSA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Options[clientcode]"

1135
------WebKitFormBoundary7BhOPSS0NpEAppSA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Options[vendorserviceurl]"

[... 80+ More Items ...]

------WebKitFormBoundary7BhOPSS0NpEAppSA--
```

what I would like to do is something like this -

```
Cypress.Commands.add("formRequest", (info: ReqInfo) => {
    cy.readFile("./fixtures/uploadBlob.txt", "utf-8").then(fixture => {
        const blob = Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(fixture, "application/text");
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blob, "uploadBlob.txt");

        return cy.request({
            url: info.url,
            method: info.method,
            headers: info.headers,
            form: true,
            body: formData
        })
    })
});
```

`info` looks like this -

```
let info : ReqInfo = {
   method: "POST",
   url : 'https://uat-delivery.acisky.com/Delivery/bkfs/Start',
   headers: {
       'Authority': 'uat-delivery.acisky.com',
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7BhOPSS0NpEAppSA',
       'Path': '/DeliveryUpload/bkfs/UploadFile',
       'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
       'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
       'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
       }
 }
```

Here is the error that I'm getting -

```
From Node.js Internals:
  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
      at Function.from (buffer.js:333:9)
      at Object.sendPromise
```

And finally I've tried multiple iterations of `XMLHttpRequest()` based on these -

- [In Cypress sending form data using POST request is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703720/in-cypress-sending-form-data-using-post-request-is-not-working)
- [Multipart formdata POST request just doesn't work in Cypress for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939625/multipart-formdata-post-request-just-doesnt-work-in-cypress-for-me)
- [How to Upload txt file with Cypress for API Testing - XMLHTTPRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160256/how-to-upload-txt-file-with-cypress-for-api-testing-xmlhttprequest)

For example -

```
Cypress.Commands.add("formRequest", (info: ReqInfo) => {
    cy.readFile("./fixtures/uploadBlob.txt", "utf-8").then(fixture => {
        const blob = Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(fixture, "application/text");
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blob, "uploadBlob.txt");

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'text';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log(xhr.response);
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open(info.method, info.url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authority', 'uat-delivery.acisky.com'),
        xhr.send(formData);

    })
```

but here I am getting the error -

```
{"errors":["No file found in request"]}
```

even though I can see that the `ReadFile` is working correctly.

The reason I am going the readFile/fixture route with the `WebKitBoundry` is because there are over 80 "fields" and in the future, we are going to need 20-30 variations of this file.

If anyone has any ideas of how to accomplish this task, I would love the help.

Thank you

Comment: where you able to find a solution to `the first argument must be....` problem? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @Edward - I just posted my answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting an update incase anyone comes across this of how I solved it.

```
        it('Should Upload the ACI document', () => {

            let url = format(aci_url, ENV.env, workOrder.workOrderId, integrator.postfix)

            cy.visitURL(url).enter().then(iFrame => {
                iFrame().find(UploadDocPage.pageBody).then(input => {
                        cy.fixture("./files/" + UploadDocPage.fixtureName, 'binary')
                            .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
                            .then(fileContent => {
                                cy.wrap(input).attachFile({
                                    fileContent: fileContent,
                                    filePath: UploadDocPage.fixtureName
                             }).task("log", `Document Attached`)
                        })
                    }).wait(5000)

                iFrame().waitForElement(UploadDocPage.goButton).click({force: true})
                iFrame().waitForElement(UploadDocPage.deliverButton).click({force: true})
                cy.task("log", `Document Sent`)
            })
        })
```

What made this even more difficult was that it was in an iFrame().

The file was an ACI document ("TestFile.ACI") - Essentially it takes the fixture as a binary, turns it into a blob string, and then sends the string to the "Input".

Answer (score 8):

The example below can help you:

```
    cy.fixture("xml.xml", 'binary')
        .then((file) => Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(file))
        .then((blob) => {

            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("file", blob, "xml.xml");

            cy.request({
                url: "/api",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                body: formdata
            }).its('status').should('be.equal', 200)
        })
```

In order to use multipart/form-data in cypress, we need to create a instance of the call `FormData` above.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the existing answers in my case no iframe was in use. The solutiom provided by [@Leonardo Pignato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16595084/leonardo-pignato) worked, but when but when I returned `cy.request`, the response in the chain had a body, but it was an ArrayBuffer. To use the response body as an object, with inspiration from [this pr](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/16576/files) I ended up with the following:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('fileRequest', (filePath: string, requestOptions: ReqInfo) => {
    return cy
        .fixture(filePath, 'binary')
        .then(file => {
            const blob = Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(file);
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.set('file', blob);

            return cy.request({
                ...requestOptions,
                // NB! Make sure you don't have form: true - this made cypress throw the same error as OP
                body: formData,
            });
        })
        .then(response => {
            const dec = new TextDecoder();

            // This assumes your API responds with JSON
            return JSON.parse(dec.decode(response.body));
        });
});
```

Sample usage:

```js
interface FileUploadResponseBody {
    name: string;
}

cy.fileRequest('uploadBlob.txt', {
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://localhost:3000/file`,
}).then((body: FileUploadResponseBody) => {
    console.log(body.name);
});
```

Tested with:
chrome 107, cypress 10.11.0, typescript 4.8.4